# Using \n correctly

Tags: c#

For this code, it only shows the Net Pay (last line of code). I thought I was suppose to do something like `lblDisplay.Text = "Gross Pay: " + grossPay;\n"State Income Tax Deduction: " + stateIncome;` But it isn't working because it says "/" is an unexpected character.

None of this surprises me, because whenever I have used \n before it was always inside the "". But if I have the `+ grossPay;` at the end for example, how do I make the \n work?

```
        lblDisplay.Text = "Gross Pay: " + grossPay;
        lblDisplay.Text = "State Income Tax Deduction: " + stateIncome;
        lblDisplay.Text = "Federal Income Tax Deduction: " + federalIncome;
        lblDisplay.Text = "Social Security Deduction: " + socialSecurity;
        lblDisplay.Text = "Medicare Deduction: " + medicare;
        lblDisplay.Text = "Net Pay: " + netPay;
```

Comment: `lblDisplay.Text = "Gross Pay: " + grossPay + "\nState Income Tax Deduction: " + stateIncome;` ...

Comment: It needs to be inside quotes. It's a string

Comment: Also, if you are wanting to display multiple lines of text, I would recommend using a `TextBox` or `TextBlock` rather than a `Label`.

Comment: Use environment.newline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is better coded using `string.Format`, saves you some typing, and less chance of errors in string formatting:

```
lblDisplay.Text = string.Format(
        "Gross Pay: {0} " +
        "\nState Income Tax Deduction: {1}" +
        "\n Federal Income Tax Deduction: {2}" +
        "\n Social Security Deduction: {3}" +
        "\n Medicare Deduction: {4}" +
        "\n Net Pay: {5}", 
        grossPay, stateIncome, federalIncome, socialSecurity, medicare, netPay);
```

Or alternatively, if you dislike all those pluses and `\n`:

```
lblDisplay.Text = string.Format(
@"Gross Pay: {0} 
State Income Tax Deduction: {1}
Federal Income Tax Deduction: {2}
Social Security Deduction: {3}
Medicare Deduction: {4}
Net Pay: {5}", 
grossPay, stateIncome, federalIncome, socialSecurity, medicare, netPay);
```

Or the $@ syntax in C# 6.0, if you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make multiple lines with a string, I recommend you use the `$@""` string. This will allow you to do somtheing like this:

lblDisplay.Text = $@"GrossPay: {grossPay}
State Income Tax Deduction: {stateIncome}";

the `@` allows you to make a multiline string and the `$`allows you to interpolate strings, using expressions in `{}` will replace them in the string.

Note that the `$` prefix is a C# 6.0 feature. If you don't have access to this features, I would look at `string.Format(string, params object[])`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do something like this:

```
 lblDisplay.Text = "Gross Pay: " + grossPay;
 lblDisplay.Text += "\n State Income Tax Deduction: " + stateIncome;
 lblDisplay.Text += "\n Federal Income Tax Deduction: " + federalIncome;
 lblDisplay.Text += "\n Social Security Deduction: " + socialSecurity;
 lblDisplay.Text += "\n Medicare Deduction: " + medicare;
 lblDisplay.Text += "\n Net Pay: " + netPay;
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking your code as written, you are assigning a new value to `lblDisplay.Text` on each row. It is not cumulative.

I prefer [Abels Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32513202/4665) with the multiline literal string, but I am going to introduce you to [Environment.NewLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
lblDisplay.Text = "Gross Pay: " + grossPay;
lblDisplay.Text += Environment.NewLine + "State Income Tax Deduction: " + stateIncome; //Etc
```